# Getting file contents from TEE's Tf.Cmd command line

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, team-explorer

I am trying to get the file contents from a specific revision in TEE. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413270(v=vs.100).aspx the command should be something to the affect of : `tf print -version:C1999 Class1.java`. This is the error I am receiving:

```
An argument error occurred: The specified file does not exist at the specified version.
```

I know I am logged in and my credentials are cached as I am able to query for information like the History command. I  also know that the file does exist in this revision as I am getting the information from the history query. Also using Tf.Exe (provided by visual studios) I am able to successfully run :

```
tf view -version:C1999 Class1.java
```

and get the contents perfectly fine. Unfortunately for this purpose I am unable to use tf.exe, and it has to the the TEE command line using Tf.Cmd, and they do not support the "view" command.

Any help on getting the file contents would be greatly appreciated.

edit- note I am using the full file path, and, as I said, it works perfectly fine in Tf.exe. Also I have tried using "$/" as the project root and still do not have any success.

Comment: What's the version of TEE do you use?

Comment: TEE-CLC-14.120.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the latest version of [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases).

> To use this command, the **Read** permission on the file that you are
>   trying to print must be set to **Allow**.

Even though you could get tf view command to work. Also double check if you have related permission on that specific file.

Comment: How do I verify that? The according to the -help prompt that appears when you type incorrect commands, neither "permission" or "perm" (both commands that I have seen used online for TEE) exist, apparently.